# CruiseControl with SourceSafe through Citrix

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, visual-sourcesafe, citrix

I'm trying to set up CruiseControl.Net using SourceSafe as our source code repository. Looking at the example code in the CC.Net documentation I need to provide a path to the SourceSafe executable in the config file:

```
<sourcecontrol type="vss">
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS\win32\SS.EXE</executable>
  <project>$/CCNET</project>
  <username>buildguy</username>
  <password>buildguypw</password>
  <ssdir>c:\repos\</ssdir>
  <applyLabel>false</applyLabel>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <alwaysGetLatest>false</alwaysGetLatest>
  <workingDirectory>c:\myBuild</workingDirectory>
  <culture>fr-FR</culture>
  <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
  <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Sadly, we're running SourceSafe through Citrix so I don't have direct access to the SourceSafe executable. Any ideas how to get around this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't get this to work without direct access to the exe.

Comment: Thanks OJ, that's what I was afraid of. I'm now fighting IT to get a local copy installed.

Comment: Yeah sorry to be the bearer of bad news mate, but Citrix is biting you hard there. You'll need it local. You might be able to use something like SourceOffSite from SourceGear, but I still think that Citrix will hurt you that way too. Good luck :)